# Facebook Audience Network SDK for Unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, networking, sdk, audience

I import the Unity `Audience Network SDK 5.4.1` package to unity, any version and it gives me this error:

> Assets\AudienceNetwork\Editor\AudienceNetworkPostprocess.cs(25,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'iOS' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

if i remove the ios part and try to work on android only - nothing works, i try to play a reward scene and i get this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   AudienceNetwork.Utility.AdUtility.IsInitialized () (at Assets/AudienceNetwork/Library/AdUtility.cs:50)
>   RewardedVideoAdScene.Awake () (at Assets/AudienceNetwork/Scenes/RewardedVideo/RewardedVideoAdScene.cs:21)

Is there a way to make this work? am i doing something wrong or missing something?
does the previous plugin works? any links to it?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what you removed the second issue is hard to tackle ...

All we can say is that it refers to the line `51`

```c#
 AndroidJavaObject context = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");
```

where most probably `currentActivity` is `null` if executed on a PC since the line `50` right before

```c#
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
```

might not work in this case.

---

The first one sounds like a "bug".

You can use [`#if` pre-processors](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) with [`UNITY_IOS`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) as a hotfix for at least making the Compiler error go away like

```c#
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2014-present, Facebook, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * You are hereby granted a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free license to use,
 * copy, modify, and distribute this software in source code or binary form for use
 * in connection with the web services and APIs provided by Facebook.
 *
 * As with any software that integrates with the Facebook platform, your use of
 * this software is subject to the Facebook Developer Principles and Policies
 * [http://developers.facebook.com/policy/]. This copyright notice shall be
 * included in all copies or substantial portions of the software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR
 * COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER
 * IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN
 * CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */
namespace AudienceNetwork.Editor
{
    using System.IO;
    using UnityEditor;
    using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
#if UNITY_IOS
    using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;
#endif
    using UnityEngine;

    public static class XCodePostProcess
    {
        public static string AudienceNetworkFramework = "FBAudienceNetwork.framework";
        public static string AudienceNetworkAAR = "AudienceNetwork.aar";
        public static string FrameworkDependenciesKey = "FrameworkDependencies";
        public static string RequiredFrameworks = "AdSupport;StoreKit;WebKit";

        [PostProcessBuild(100)]
        public static void OnPostProcessBuild(BuildTarget target, string path)
        {
#if UNITY_IOS
            if (target == BuildTarget.iOS) {
                string projectPath = PBXProject.GetPBXProjectPath(path);
                PBXProject project = new PBXProject();
                project.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(projectPath));
                string targetName = PBXProject.GetUnityTargetName();
                string targetGUID = project.TargetGuidByName(targetName);
                project.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGUID, "AdSupport.framework", false);
                project.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGUID, "StoreKit.framework", false);
                project.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGUID, "WebKit.framework", false);

                File.WriteAllText(projectPath, project.WriteToString());
            }
#endif

            PluginImporter[] importers = PluginImporter.GetAllImporters();
            PluginImporter iOSPlugin = null;
            PluginImporter androidPlugin = null;
            foreach (PluginImporter importer in importers)
            {
                if (importer.assetPath.Contains(AudienceNetworkFramework))
                {
                    iOSPlugin = importer;
                    Debug.Log("Audience Network iOS plugin found at " + importer.assetPath + ".");
                }
                else if (importer.assetPath.Contains(AudienceNetworkAAR))
                {
                    androidPlugin = importer;
                    Debug.Log("Audience Network Android plugin found at " + importer.assetPath + ".");
                }
            }
            if (iOSPlugin != null)
            {
                iOSPlugin.SetCompatibleWithAnyPlatform(false);
                iOSPlugin.SetCompatibleWithEditor(false);
                iOSPlugin.SetCompatibleWithPlatform(BuildTarget.iOS, true);
                iOSPlugin.SetPlatformData(BuildTarget.iOS, FrameworkDependenciesKey, RequiredFrameworks);
                iOSPlugin.SaveAndReimport();
            }
            if (androidPlugin != null)
            {
                androidPlugin.SetCompatibleWithAnyPlatform(false);
                androidPlugin.SetCompatibleWithEditor(false);
                androidPlugin.SetCompatibleWithPlatform(BuildTarget.Android, true);
                androidPlugin.SaveAndReimport();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No warranty that this fixes all your issues, though.

---

[Google Ads](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/882) had a similar error and used kind of the same hotfix.

---

Otherwise you might want to consider installing the IOS build support which I guess would also make the error go away (but fills unnecessarily disk space of course in case you only want to build for Android)

Comment: Thats exactly what i have done and if fixed the first issue, the second one appears when i go to the scene and try to play it - im trying to understand why it returns the error.

Comment: Hey I updated the first part of the answer .. I guess the problem is that it might not run on a PC(in the editor) but only on the phone ... sounds a bit to me like Facebook dudes were a bit lazy catching these cases

Comment: Tried to build - it get stuck in the middle of build on the Interstitial Scene for long time and doesnt get further, i wonder when they will fix this build :(

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** in AdUtility.cs Add:

```
"#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR" 

internal static bool IsInitialized()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
```